# Class PDO not found in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, pdo, laravel-5

i have a DB helper and code is in this way:

```
<?php

namespace App\Business;

use DB;

Class DBHelper{

    private function dbConnectionInfo()


    {

    //$results = DB::select('Select UserName from user_master');
            //return "fetchUserLocation success". json_encode($results) ;
        $pdo_db = DB::connection()->getPdo() ;
        $pdo_db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $pdo_db;

    }   

    function executeResultSet($DBQuery)
    {
        $pdo_object = DBHelper :: dbConnectionInfo();
        $stmt = $pdo_object->prepare($DBQuery);
        $stmt->execute();
        $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $results;
    }

    function dbConnection()
    {
        return  DBHelper :: dbConnectionInfo();
    }
}

?>
```

When i call return "fetchUserLocation success". json_encode($results) ; it executed that means DB connection works properly but when i call the function error : Class 'App\Business\PDO' not found
How can i use PDO in this code. please suggest

Comment: why you need to use PDO with laravel ? why not laravel illuminate ?

Comment: what do you want to say......please explain

Comment: Have you gone through laravel documentation or laracast ?

Comment: actually im integrated a project from drupel to laravel, I have to use PDO. Please tell the solution

Comment: Read https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database

Comment: You do not need to write your own function  for operation, the functions are there you only need to get it correctly and use.

Answer (score 2):

Write \PDO instead of PDO, because it is searching PDO inside your namespace instead of searching 'PDO' in the root namespace.

Comment: You can't have `Class 'App\Business\PDO' not found ` anymore. The error has changed, or you didn't replace all the PDO by \PDO.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to:

Install PDO support.
Enable PDO in your PHP configuration. This can be done by adding the following:

```
extension=pdo.so

extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

to your `php.ini` file.

Answer (score 0):

this is your problem, this PDO:: does not exist, you are doing the raw pdo thing instead of the one your dependencies. this is what you should do

```
$results = $stmt->fetchAll($pdo_object::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Using this actually works replacing the pdo for the getPDO works